# Terminal colors putty raspbian

Tags: ssh, colors, putty, raspbian

I'm connecting to my Raspberry Pi from my Windows Machine using putty. I already adjusted the colors for bold blue in putty to be more readable (using [this](http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows) guide).
But I still have problems with the colors in my terminal: for example when I run htop, the first value for the load average is completely black, or the swap values are not readable.
When I copy the text through to windows into a text file it's readable.

Can somebody please help me figure out where to adjust the settings?

Comment: You may also be able to customise the settings of Putty. This will give you the fine grained control.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, *[Improving Putty settings on Windows](http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows)* gives more/less the same advice I would give for PuTTY.  The question is unclear *which* values OP used for blue.

I took a look at PuTTY with the suggested settings, and except for the "MC" color scheme below, did not see any real difference in the blue's used for that versus with xterm.

According to the manual page, `htop` is ncurses-based.  It uses the ncurses `use_default_colors` extension (see the first screenshot), and does not use `LS_COLORS` or similar *command-line kludges*.

`htop` has a set of built-in color schemes which you can select via the <kbd>F2</kbd> (Setup) menu.  At least the black-on-white should work.  But here are screenshots of the choices.  You would probably find "MC" the most legible:

[image: htop with "default" scheme]

[image: htop with "monochromatic" scheme]

[image: htop with "black on white" scheme]

[image: htop with "light terminal" scheme]

[image: htop with "MC" scheme]

[image: htop with "Black Night" scheme]

[image: htop with "Broken Gray" scheme]

Further reading:

- [I don't like that shade of blue](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#dont_like_blue)

[image: screenshot from XTerm FAQ]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Raspberry, but in SUSE you need to change (if you are root and want to do it system wide) `/etc/DIR_COLORS` or make your own users in your startup script. Most probably you will need to change the colors in your Raspberry to display them correctly with putty.

Debian systems have LS_COLORS variable which contains the values, so you will need to locate where Raspberry keeps that.

I had the same problem with that SUSE machine and solved it that way.

Comment: OK, I just fund out that with `dircolors` or `echo $LS_COLORS` I can display all the colors. By connecting a small screen I had lying around I could see that the color in question is something like a dark grey/green. How can I now find out which color it is exactly and ban this one from my terminal.

Comment: You have a list of the codes in http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors. Just change the value to a light grey/green and you will be good to go.

Comment: Rasbian is Debian (but compiled for Raspberry-pi), so just follow this advice for Debian.

Comment: see [single rule for apostrophes](https://wordpress.com/view/ctrlaltdelor.wordpress.com) for how to do them.